# Obscure string in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, sed, glob, tr

I am trying to do the following:

```
obscure ( ) {
    local txt="$1"
    echo "$txt" | tr '[:alnum:]' '*'
}
```

So that if I do:

```
obscure 'mysecretstring'
```

I get:

```
**************
```

What matcher can I use for `tr`, instead of `[:alnum:]` to mean 'any character'?

Is there a better way to implement `obscure`? Another option that comes to mind is `sed`.

Comment: If you want to mean _any printable character_, you could use `[:print:]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use pure BASH:

```
obscure() {
   local txt="$1"
   echo "${txt//?/*}"
}
```

`"${txt//?/*}"` will replace each character in `$txt` by `*`

Test it:

```
obscure 'mysecretstring3123213213'
************************

obscure mysecretstring
**************

obscure '!@#$%^&*()_+=-'
**************

obscure '中文版'
***
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: You don't even need the local variable: `echo "${1//?/*}"` works as well.

Comment: Yes that's true local variable isn't needed for this. Even for `tr` it wasn't needed.